# PhoneGap 3.3.0 crashes on URLforFilesystemPath: selector

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, cordova

Ok so I updated to Phonegap 3.3.0. and now fileTransfer.download crashes at runtime on iOS with the message:

```
[CDVAssetLibraryFilesystem URLforFilesystemPath:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14d14ea0'
```

so I went to the CDVAssetLibraryFilesystem.h and CDVAssetLibraryFilesystem.m and added a dummy function:

```
- (NSString*) URLforFilesystemPath:(NSString*)path{
    return nil;
}
```

which avoids the crash but the file download fails...

```
File Transfer Error: Could not create target file
```

Did they just forget to implement it? Does anyone have the code from a previous version??

Thanks

Comment: have you added the plugin and updated the platform?

Answer (score 5):

Try changing **fullPath** to **toURL()**

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, 
    function(fileSystem){  //success
        //nativeLocalRootPath = fileSystem.root.fullPath; //old way
        nativeLocalRootPath = fileSystem.root.toURL(); //3.3.0
    }, function(){} //fail
);
```

[Cordova FileEntry Doc](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileEntry)